# Dart - Can I handle null value from json.decode when the key we put is wrong

Tags: json, dart

Can we handle null value output from json.decode? I already try using if else function, but it doesn't really works well.

```
import 'dart:convert';
var typeCat = "WrongKey";
var endPoint = "WrongKey";

void main() async {
  final base = RetryClient(http.Client());
  String outputJSON = await base.read(
      Uri.parse("http://estra-api.herokuapp.com/api/${typeCat}/${endPoint}"));
  final link_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["link"] as String;
  final text_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["text"] as String;
  print(link_decode);
  print(text_decode);
}
```

Is there anything I can do with these codes?

Comment: which line is giving you the error?

Comment: the variable link_decode and text_decode

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: well it's just null output, but I wanted it handle it with other string words

Comment: try to use the ?? operator as in the answer below

Comment: @user17723683 hi.. have you found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure since you didn't share the full error message, but the problem seem to be that you're trying to cast to a `non-nullable String` a value that can possibly be `null`.

```
  final link_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["link"] as String?;
  final text_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["text"] as String?;
```

and if you want to assign a default value for them you can also:

```
  final link_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["link"] ?? 'default';
  final text_decode = json.decode(outputJSON)["text"] ?? 'default';
```

This will allow `link_decode` and `text_decode` to have `null` as value

Try this and if you don't succede share the error message.